# How to safely allow PUT for single program in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento2, put, mod-security

I am using Magento (version 2.2.5) and I seem to need to allow PUT requests for my server (at least for the Magento program).

For specifics, on Magento entering a discount code does not work on the checkout page fails "501 (Not Implemented)". However the discount code section does work in the shopping cart page. The difference seems to be that the shopping cart page uses GET method while the checkout page uses PUT method.

How do I enable PUT method to work for Magento? Is this something which can be done through .htaccess? If it needs to be done for the entire server, is there any security risk to allow PUT requests?

I have seen somewhere that this might be related to Apache's "mod_security". I am new at this and I do not want to expose the server to any potential vulnerabilities.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apache allows PUT by default, but there are many different way to prohibit said method. ModSecurity (via custom rules or the Core Rule Set) is one of them. However, status code 501 is not used by ModSecurity by default. It can be customized though, but I doubt it.

Under the line, I do not think you can solve this mystery without access to the error-log of the server or communicating with somebody who has access.

Comment: thank you for responding. This is an issue that seems to affect Magento 2 users with Apache servers so if you could help we would all be very appreciative. When trying to use the PUT command the server responds with the 501 error ("This method may not be used."). I have not done any particular edits to mod_security (nor am I aware if it was setup altogether; the setup was just basic apache 2.4). There are no errors being output onto the apache2 error log. What else should I check? How do I check the mod_security settings?

Comment: one more note: using phpinfo() I cannot find "mod_security" even listed as an installed module in my apache. Something else must be blocking the PUT call. What can it be?

Comment: There are many different options. Check for mod_allowmethods.
Usually, I find it easier to start with a minimal configuration and then building it up again until the error surfaces than the other way around. https://netnea.com has a nice minimal config in the 2nd of the apache tutorials.